# Trying to cast a boxed int to byte

Tags: c#, .net, casting, c#-2.0

Code to illustrate :

```
        int i = 5;
        object obj = i;
        byte b = (byte)obj; // X
```

When run, this generates a System.InvalidCastException ("Specified cast is not valid") at line "X". Doing a double cast works :

```
        byte b = (byte)(int)obj;
```

I would have thought that you ought to be able to cast a boxed int (if it has a value in the range 0..255) to a byte. Can anyone shed any light on this ?

(This is in .net 2.0, in case that matters).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference in behaviour you're seeing is the difference between [identity and representation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/representation-and-identity).

Unboxing is an *identity* cast, and a *representation-preserving* operation.  Casting an `int` to a `byte`, however, is *representation-changing* (since there is a potential loss of precision).

You get an `InvalidCastException` when you try to unbox the `int` as a `byte` because the **identity** of the boxed value is not a `byte`, it is an `int`.  When you write `byte b = (byte)obj`, you are telling the runtime, *I know that what's in there **is** a `byte`*, but what you really mean to say is, *I think that what's in there can be **converted** to a `byte`*.

In order to make the latter statement, you first have to declare the *identity* of the object, which is an `int`.  Then and only then can you make a representation-changing conversion to `byte`.

Note that this applies even if the target type is "larger" - i.e. an `Int64`.  *All* explicit conversions for which the destination type is not in the inheritance tree of the source type are considered to be representation-changing.  And since all types derive from `System.Object`, unboxing by definition **cannot** change the representation.

Answer (score 5):

[MSDN explicitly says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) that unboxing to a different type will throw an `InvalidCastException`.

My understanding is that the type to which a variable is unboxed is actually a parameter to the [underlying CIL assembly command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.unbox.aspx). It is `unbox` opcode that actually throws the `InvalidCastException`.

> InvalidCastException  is thrown if the
>   object is not boxed as valType.