# Filter result is filtering with a byte and not with an integer value using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to bind my `TableAdapters` result in a `dropdownlist`, just now, I'm using:

```
DropDownBinding.Bind<Cat_AgTableAdapter>(CbxAg, "Cod", "AgenV", Convert.ToInt32(CbxReg.SelectedValue));

public static void Bind<T>(DropDownList dropDown, string textField, string valueField, int filter, string method, bool defaultSelect) where T : new()
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var typeMethod = type.GetMethod(method);

            var clase = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            dropDown.DataSource = typeMethod.Invoke(clase, new object[] { filter });
            dropDown.DataTextField = textField;
            dropDown.DataValueField = valueField;
            dropDown.DataBind();

            if (defaultSelect)
                dropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select an option--", "-1"));
        }
```

But in the line:
`dropDown.DataSource = typeMethod.Invoke(clase, new object[] { filter });`
is giving me the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Byte'.
```

Comment: filter parameter type is Int32, I suppose your method require byte, but not Int32...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While implicitly casting from int to byte works in regular cases, it cannot be performed through a boxed int (int as object type). See a similar issue here: [trying-to-cast-a-boxed-int-to-byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970967/trying-to-cast-a-boxed-int-to-byte).

Since the method expects a byte, but you pass an integer, you need to *explicitly cast it to byte* before invoking the method:

```
dropDown.DataSource = typeMethod.Invoke(clase, new object[] { (byte)filter });
```